# Issue deleting rows from displayed table

Tags: php, sql, delete-row

So I have an issue getting rows to be deleted using the following code. The table displays the information correctly, plus sends the correct id in the url to the delete.php page, but I cannot get it to complete the command. Changing the code slightly on the `delete.php` I can get it to show either:

> Couldn't delete the index.

or:

> Binding parameters failed: 0

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY `server_name`;"))
{
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><b>Server Name</b></th>
<th><center><b>Port</b></center></th>
<th><center><b>Mod</b></center></th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['server_name']; ?></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['server_port']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['mod']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['index']; ?>"><img src="images/remove.png" width="16" height="16"></center></img></a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>
```

My delete file is

```
    <?php
// Your database info
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'pass';
$db_name = 'database';

if (!isset($_GET['id']))
{
    echo 'No ID was given...';
    exit;
}

$con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') ' . $con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE 'index' = " . $_GET['id'];
if (!$result = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

if (!$result->bind_param('i', $_GET['ID']))
{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if (!$result->execute())
{
    die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if ($result->affected_rows > 0)
{
    echo "The ID was deleted with success.";
}
else
{
    echo "Couldn't delete the index.";
}
$result->close();
$con->close();
```

It has to be something simple but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation when you're using a prepared statement, instead of using a `?` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of quotes in your SQL. To escape a table or column name that contains a reserved word, you use backticks. And if you're using `bind_param`, you have to put `?` in the query where the parameter will be substituted.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE `index` = ?";
```

Comment: Wow guys, that was quick and simple! I actually had ?" originally, but when it wouldnt work, I started changing things and getting myself all confused. What I didnt have at that time, was the ' around index.. adding them later on but moving on from ?" .. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line in your `delete.php` file:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE 'index' = " . $_GET['id'];
```

with:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE `index` = ?";
```

Changes in the suggested replacement statement include:

1. Replace single quotes around column name `index` with backticks.  Note that MySQL escape character is a backtick not single quotes.
2. You are not including any parameter placeholders in your `delete` query but further down you are attempting to bind an integer parameter.

Comment: Thanks Vee! I gave the correct answer to Barmar as he was just quicker then you, but you also had the right answer! thanks mate.